# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to Run a simple TesNG test in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

Please find the below code i am trying to execute , I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error when i try to run it as TestNG Test

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class First 
{

    @Test
    public void dispaly()
    {

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Error :
An internal error occurred during: "Launching First".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you please provide a full Stacktrace instead of an Error Message. As well as the whole class please?

Comment: "An internal error" - something is wrong inside Eclipse.  It is not necessarily related to your code.  TestNG is not officially supported by the Eclipse team, so the plugin may simply not be up to date.

Comment: It worked after installing all the updates of Eclipse .